# using dask for sending parallel API request and error handling

Tags: python, api, parallel-processing, dask

I started using dask recently. I want to send data to a REST API using http request, the API return a json file to verify if the data upload is successful or not. Here is my API call function:

```
def requestToAPI():
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    data = {
      "api_key" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "attributes" : [
       {
         "external_id" : "user1",
         "app_id" : "xxxx-xxx-xxxxx-xxxx",
         "firs_name" : "user_firstname",
         "last_name" : "user_lastname_test"
       }
     ]
    }
    r = requests.post('https://abcdf.com/users/abdcgdu', headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
    return r.json()
```

I have a number of dask dataframe chunk that I get from below code:

```
 rChunk=dd.from_pandas(pandaDataFrame, chunksize=1000)
```

How can I use dask and use above chunks(assume each chunk will change to proper json file) to send parallel request to API and do proper error handling if one of the request fail/return error?

I tried to use dask.delayed:

[delayed(requestToAPI)(chunk) for chunk in rChunk]

but not sure how can I do the proper error handling??

Comment: What so you wish to do in the case of an error?

Comment: @mdurant just print out the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that dask dataframe is the best choice for your application.  You might want to look at the delayed, futures, or bag APIs.

I would probably use concurrent.futures

```
from dask.distributed import Client, as_completed

futures = client.map(process, requests)
for future in as_completed(futures):
    try:
        response = future.result()
        # do stuff with result
    except Exeption:
        # do stuff
```

http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html

Comment: what are the process and requests here?

Comment: process=requestToAPI; requests=rChunk